# How can I detect a string that is mostly number

Tags: python, python-re

In a python program I want to filter string which are mostly numbers, such as the results of experiments in a table etc.

For example, a string like "year 2004 2005 2006" or "dimension 2.343m 3.85m 343.5m" must be filtered.

I know how to check if string contains number by `any(i.isdigit() for i in str)` but how to count them? I can do that with a loop, but I look for a similar function to do it inline.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Thanks I think I can figure it out (`s.isdigit() or s == "."`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `count` digits in string and check that count of digit for example bigger than `len()//2` or not like below:

```
>>> st = "year 2004 2005 2006"
>>> sum(s.isdigit() for s in st) > len(st)//2
True

>>> st2 = "year year year 2006"
>>> sum(s.isdigit() for s in st2) > len(st2)//2
False

# for more explanation
>>> [s.isdigit() for s in st2]
[False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True]

>>> sum(s.isdigit() for s in st2)
4
```

Comment: does sum count Trues in the loop you showed ?

Comment: @Ahmad yes this is correct

Answer (score 2):

If understand your question correctly you are looking for `sum`

```
>>> sum(1 for i in str if i.isdigit())
```

Comment: Thanks, while the question could be simile I think it;s useful. please vote it up otherwise I am forced to delete it.